# Setting up user restrictions in a LAMP app

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three tables that display what user saves in  database (details_letter Table, Address_details Table, and Signatories Table) 
and three users (Manager, HR, Legal officer) currently when the three users are logged in, they are able to view each others' saved content.

How can I create it in a way that the manager can view HR and Legal officer's saved content, but HR and Legal officer can't view each others' saved database content?

```
LOGIN FORM:

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta id="_moz_html_fragment">
        </head>
        <body style="background-image:url(ocean5.jpeg)">
            <div style="text-align: center;"><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <big>
                    <big>LETTER&nbsp; HEAD SYSTEM
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </big>
                </big>
                <form method="post" action="login.php">
                    <center>
                    <table width="30%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">USERNAME<br></td>
                                <td><input name="username" type="text"><br></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">PASSWORD<br></td>
                                <td><input name="password" type="password"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <form method="post" action="view.php">
                        <input value="LOGIN" name="submit" type="submit"><br>

                    </form>
                    </center>
                </form>
                <big>
                    <big>
                        <br>
                    </big>
                </big>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should use style sheets to align your elements, not <br>s.

Comment: you need to save `type also in your table`for users and based o that type put the restriction that what much amount of record need to show to the logged-in user based on his type.

Answer (score 0):

> add role column to your user table or create a role table.

Then applying some logic like this

if ( $user->role == "Admin" ) { //doSomeThing }

I hope this will help you.

Comment: let me try will give you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I generally have a `userPerms` column in my `users` table.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN userPerms int not null default 1
```

My general rankings are:

- 0 = Banned
- 1 = Normal User
- 2 = Unused
- 3 = Unused
- 4 = Admin
- 5 = Super Admin

I recommend before making a website that is going to be using a database, that you plan out your database and what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the role of PHP sessions. When the user is logged in, the respective session can be started. The stated sessions can separate the users to view the own contents.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['manager']){
// contents of manager
}
if($_SESSION['HR']){
// contents of HR
}
if($_SESSION['legalofficer']){
// contents of legalofficer
}else{
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```